# Getting the selected value and rest of the value in the drop down list on onchange

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to display the selected value of that particular id in a drop down list on clicking the edit button of that id along with rest of the values in the drop down list which enable to update the selected value to some other value in the drop down list on updation.

**edit.php**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select  class="form-control" name="project" id="project" required>

      </select>
    </div>                       
  </div>
</div>

$("#type").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val(); //gives the type value
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  var editid = document.getElementById("editidhidden").value; //editidhidden gives the id

  if (id=="dir") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "edit_ajax.php",
      data: {
        id: id, 
        editid: editid,
        dir :1,
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#project").html(html);
      } 
    }); 
  }
});
```

**edit_ajax.php**

```
if($_POST['dir'])
{
   $id=$_POST['id'];
   $editid=$_POST['editid'];

   $sql="SELECT * FROM project WHERE direct_type='$id'";
   $result=$conn->query($sql);
   //echo '<option selected="selected" value="">'.$roweditcategory['value'].'</option>';
   while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
   {
     $sqleditcategory="SELECT * FROM booking WHERE id='$editid'";
      $resulteditcategory=$conn->query($sqleditcategory);
      $roweditcategory=$resulteditcategory->fetch_assoc();
      $id=$row['direct_intcode'];
      $data=$row['direct_name'];
      if($roweditcategory['value']==$id)
      {
         echo '<option value="'.$id.'" selected="selected">'.$data.'</option>';
      }
      echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you post a mock ux?

Comment: you want to edit an input, which is a select, so  you want to show the current value as selected with other options, and on change you want to update. ??

Comment: you code seems right, what is the issue you getting?

Comment: @AhmedSunny Ya i want to show the current value as selected with other options and on change I want to update that.